# I am trying to delete specific image from multiple input type but not deleting using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have Multiple image uploader a/c to my code when I click to delete the specific image but unfortunately, it's not deleting from the input type please help me how can I resolve that thanks.

**html view**

```
    <input name="file[]" type="file" class="file" id="files" multiple  required/>
```

**javascript**

```
/** SHOW IMAGES */
function showImages() {
    container.innerHTML = files.reduce((prev, curr, index) => {
        return `${prev}
            <div class="image">
                <span  onclick="delImage(${index})">&times;</span>
                <img src="${URL.createObjectURL(curr)}" />
            </div>`

    }, '');
}


 /* DELETE IMAGE */
    function delImage(index) {
    files.splice(index, 1);
    
    const input = document.querySelector('#files');
        // Retrieve FileList boject
        const filess = input.files
    
        // Convert FileList to array
         const arr = Array.from(filess)
    
        // Loop through files
        for (let i = 0; i < filess.length; i++) {
               files.splice(i, 1);
        }
    showImages();
    }
```

Comment: it's impossible, internet browsers can't delete any   file on their system

Comment: @MisterJojo I don't think the OP is asking to remove a file from the local file system; I think they are hoping to remove the selected image from the multi-select file input.